Risk neutral measure in multicurve framework
Lets assume we have two stocks $S_1$ and $S_2$ which satisfy the following SDE's in the risk neutral measure
$$dS_1(t) = r_{f1}S_1dt + \sigma_1S_1dW_1(t)$$ and
$$dS_2(t) = r_{f2}S_1dt + \sigma_2S_2dW_2(t)$$
We assume that forward rates $r_{f1}$, $r_{f2}$(note that these are not the stock growth rates in real world measure) and volatilities $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ are constant. We further assume that risk free rate $r$ is constant.
From the equations, it is obvious that $$M_i(t) = \mathbf{E}[e^{-r_{fi}t}S_i(t)]$$ are martingales for $i \in [1,2]$
However, in the risk neutral measure, we should have $$M_i(t) = \mathbf{E}[e^{-rt}S_i(t)]$$ as martingale for $i \in [1,2]$.
Both facts are not consistent. How do we reconcile this? Is $S_i$ not a tradeable asset in multicurve framework somehow?

They are consistent. Forward rate of stocks do not equal the risk free rate. If the collateral is stock, the lending rate will be higher.

Borrowing, lending cost + dividends can have huge effect on forward rates.
